# How to generate a html page with posted data and create a url for the page to access?

Tags: clojure, compojure, compojure-api

I'm very new to the Clojure-Compojure API development. I have a requirement where I need to create a static html page for every post to my api, fill the content with posted body including styles and a url has to be generated to point to that static html page.

This is not a web development project but a requirement as a part of api development. The generated page has to be stored and url has to be created to point to that page.

I'm using Clojure Compojure api template.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried already? There's a basic web development guide using Compojure here: http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/basic_web_development.html

Comment: Hi Denis, thank you for your suggestion. My requirement is for every request to my api, I need to generate a .html file with the contents in the request body. Is there any way to generate .html and store inside our folders Denis? Thanks a lot for your time.